# Google classroom read only api user

Tags: google-classroom

I’m new to google classroom api. I want to create a process that will query all classes, students, assignments etc. It will run unattended.

So, my questions are:

- will offline scope allow the process to query the api unattended?
- can only an admin user see all classes, students, assignments?
- or, can a g-suite user be created with limited read-only permissions to certain resources?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an unattended batch process and Google OAuth access tokens expire after 1 hour, you will likely need offline access. You can do this by adding the parameter `access_type=offline` in the authorization URL.

In terms of actually acquiring all classes, students, assignments, etc., here are a few things to note:

- If you're a domain administrator, you can retrieve courses, students, assignments, invitations, etc. in their domain and will not need each teacher to authorize these requests.
- If you don't have domain administrator access and want to retrieve all these items, you will have to have each teacher authorize your request(s).

As for your last question, I'm not entirely sure what you mean -- could you clarify? Are you asking is if one workaround would be to create a G Suite user that has read access to all these resources and then use that account to make all the requests?

Comment: To clarify, my final question is asking if it's possible to read all resources under the classroom api without the need to be a domain administrator.  As the process I want to create will run unattended, I'm reluctant to use an offline token for a domain admin.  Therefore, I was hoping to create a user with just enough privileges to read all classroom resources

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service account and use it to query all data on behalf of users-
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority